# How can I achieve JTA-like transactional operations with a document-oriented DB such as MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, jta

Browsing around, I really struggle to find a suitable answer to this question.

I've tried my chance with Mongo's Two-phase commits as decribed here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ but it seems to be tedious and lacks distributed transactions with other tiers.

I would also need strong arguments regarding toughness and reliability.

Does anyone have achieved a successfull study or implementation in production on this ?

My underlying need is to add a Document Oriented persistence to a JCR implementation.

Thank's for helping

Comment: Get a ACID compatible database?

Comment: Or use a STM (Software Transactional memory) to manage that at the application level.

Comment: Well a STM would actually shift the issue at application level rather than solving it. The expected transaction support in my issue is meant to offer reliability over multiple and different data storage tiers (DB, FS, etc).

Comment: This question comes up frequently as some think there's a "work-around." Unfortunately, you've picked the wrong DB technology if cross-tier transactions are important to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most NoSQL databases do not support ACID or XA, except graph databases like Neo4j. Mongodb only supports atomic operation within one single document. That's why you find the so-called two phase commits in mongodb document so cumbersome. You might also want to look into if using **compensating transaction** fits your use case or not.